# Nuxt memory leak in browser side when dynamically loading a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to build a `NuxtJS` application that could load components dynamically.

With my code, I achieved that. On the server-side, the component is loaded normally, but when the page is loading then the browser faced with a huge memory leak that even doesn't allow to run a performance analysis or a memory heap snapshot.

My code is like that:

**/plugins/theme-load-method.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function ({store}) {
  Vue.prototype.loadThemeTemplate = function loadThemeTemplate(template) {
    return () => import(`~/components/themes/${store.state.config.theme}/${template}`);
  };
}
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :is="loadThemeTemplate('index.vue')" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HomePage"
};
</script>
```

**components/themes/MY_THEME_1/index.vue**

```
<template>
    <section>
        MY_THEME_1 Home Page
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ThemeHomePage",
}
</script>
```

So, do you have any idea why it is getting out of memory only on the client-side?

Comment: Does `loadThemeTemplate('index.vue')` correctly print out the path to your template? Put it inside of `created(){}` and make sure it does.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly. By this setup, when I load the page, the SSR loading the corresponding file from the `MY_THEME_1` folder, but then once the page is loaded on the browser, the browser consumes all the available memory. And the question is if someone could explain why.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/#inject-in-root--context

> Don't use Vue.use(), Vue.component(), and don't make changes to the Vue prototype or global Vue object inside the function exported by your plugin. (It would cause a memory leak on server-side.) See also global mixins .

so, you can override `Vue.prototype.loadThemeTemplate` outside those exported function